# How to add files and dirs to a zip file without the root dir?

Tags: command-line, zip

The zip utility program, when invoked as `zip -r out.zip base/*` on this directory structure

```
.
./base
./base/b
./base/b/c
./base/d
```

creates the following result

```
  adding: base/b/ (stored 0%)
  adding: base/b/c (stored 0%)
  adding: base/d (stored 0%)
```

I would like to obtain a file containing data as from the following output

```
  adding: b/ (stored 0%)
  adding: b/c (stored 0%)
  adding: d (stored 0%)
```

I expected the -j option to help me, but it does not: it completely flattens the directory structure. At the moment, the only solution I found is to cd into base and invoke zip from here, but I was wondering if there's a powerswitch I fail to recognize as such in the docs.

Comment: What utility or OS are you using?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630167/zip-command-without-including-the-compressed-dir-itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you do not want to `cd`, but...

If all else fails and you are hoping to keep your call to zip down to one line, you could chain the calls and use a relative path to output zip in the root:

For Windows:

`cd base & zip -r ..\out.zip * & cd ..`

For Linux/Unix:

`cd base ; zip -r ../out.zip * ; cd ..`