# Zip command without including the compressed dir itself

Tags: unix, zip, cmd

Suppose the structure:

```
/foo/bar/
        --file1
        --file2
        --file3
        --folder1
          --file4
        --folder2
          --file5
```

I want to run the unix [zip](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm) utility, compressing the `bar` folder and all of it's files and subfolders, from `foo` folder, but not have the `bar` folder inside the zip, using only command line.

If I try to use the `-j` argument, it doesn't create the bar folder inside the zip as I want, but doesn't create `folder1` and `folder2`. Doing `-rj` doesn't work.

(I know I can enter inside bar and do `zip -r bar.zip .` I want to know if it's possible to accomplish what $/foo/bar/ `zip -r bar.zip .` but doing it from $/foo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zip doesn't have a -C (change directory) command like tar does

you can do:

```
cd folder1 && zip -r ../bar.zip *
```

from within a command line shell

or you can use bsdtar which is a version of tar from libarchive that can create zips

```
bsdtar cf bar.zip --format zip -C folder1 .
```

(this creates a folder called ./ -- not sure a way around that)

Comment: I need to learn more about command line, "cd folder1 && zip -r ../bar.zip *" is a good solution to me. Thanks!

Comment: "bsdtar cf" creates a tar file, not a zip.

Comment: You're right, I thought it inferred from the extension like it does for extraction, but I guess it doesn't. you need to add a `--format zip` (and it looks like that doesn't always work)

Answer (score 8):

You have to do `cd /foo/bar` then `zip -r bar.zip .`, however, you can group them with parentheses to run in a subshell:

```
# instead of: cd /foo/bar; zip -r bar.zip; cd -

( cd /foo/bar; zip -r bar.zip . )
```

The enclosed (paren-grouped) commands are run in a subshell and cd within it won't affect the outer shell session.

See [sh manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh).

```
Compound Commands
    A compound command is one of the following:

    (list) list is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  
           Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.  
           The return status is the exit status of list.
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the OP's reasoning.  I was looking for this solution as well.

I am in the middle of coding a program that creates an `.ods` by building the internal xml files and zipping them together.  They must be in the root dir of the archive, or you get an error when you try and run OOo.

I'm sure there is a dozen other ways to do this:
create a blank `.ods` file in OOo named `blank.ods`, extract to dir named `blank`, then try running:

```
cd blank && zip -r ../blank.ods *
```

The way I wrote mine, the shell closes after one command, so I don't need to navigate back to the original directory, if you do simply add `&& cd ..` to the command line:

```
cd blank && zip -r ../blank.ods * && cd ..
```